# IncompatibleClassChangeError: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView

Tags: android, android-espresso

I get one really strange error when testing an activity that uses the design library:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
    at de.stephanlindauer.criticalmaps.Main.onCreate(Main.java:77)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
    at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:534)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
```

Anyone had the problem and found a way around it? The activity works outside the espresso-tests

using espresso 2.2.1

here the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1'

    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.1.1'

    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.3'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'org.ligi:AXT:0.35'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'

    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.1.0'
    testCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
}
```

Comment: please post your xml layout code for this actvity

Comment: can you post your XML file

Comment: FYI IncompatibleClassChangeError is the superclass of all classes which represent errors that occur when inconsistent class files are loaded into the same running image.

Comment: Take a look if you don't have any library duplicated, means that maybe you are adding the same library twice. (.jar and compile)

Comment: Why the hell you are downvoting ?! `IncompatibleClassChangeError` was introduced in L and its been bugging everyone especially on Samsung devices. In the android source you can find that they're catching the exception and taking some sort of default measures. In your case there is not much you can do as fallback. CTRL+F for the error in this class http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-0/android/widget/TextView.java

Comment: Please post your styles.xml

Comment: @Naveen what do you expect to see there? No style is used there and it works in the app - just not test

Comment: Can you post all you dependencies and test dependencies?

Comment: @ligi Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @JasonRobinson no :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Espresso depends on a number of support dependencies, and as of the latest version of Espresso (2.2.1), they're all out of date. You've worked around this by including *some* of them as test dependencies explicitly, but you forgot one: recyclerview-v7.

You need to either include recylerview-v7 as a test dependency or exclude it from contrib. I prefer to just exclude those dependencies so it'll default to my normal compile dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

Comment: This solution seems doesn't work me, even with espresso 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Replace with this code.Hopefully it will work.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/some_color"/>
```